# Mongo Query does not return anything

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to get all groups that have the subject chemistry and fit a given users schedule. Right now the query does not return anything. I believe there is a syntax error. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const GroupSchema = new Schema({
  owner: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'users'},
  subject: String,
  date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  mondayStart: Number,
  mondayEnd: Number,
  tuesdayStart: Number,
  tuesdayEnd: Number,
  wednesdayStart: Number,
  wednesdayEnd: Number
});

module.exports = Group = mongoose.model('groups', GroupSchema);


let query = Group.find({
  subject: '/chemistry/',
  $or: [
    {$and: [ {mondayStart: {gte: 6}}, {mondayEnd:  {lte: 8}}] },
    {$and: [ {tuesdayStart: {gte: 9}}, {tuesdayEnd: {lte:13}}] },
    {$and: [ {wednesdayStart: {gte: 9}}, {wednesdayEnd: {lte: 12}}
  ]
})
```

Comment: what's the 'syntax error' you see?

Comment: i don't see one that is just my suspicion

Comment: any output? please edit the question to include the output. maybe no such data or query may need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your query. Below given Query is working Example:

```
let query = Group.find({
        subject: {$regex :'chemistry'},
      $or: [
        {$and: [ {mondayStart: {$gte: 6}}, {mondayEnd:  {$lte: 8}}] },
        {$and: [ {tuesdayStart: {$gte: 9}}, {tuesdayEnd: {$lte:13}}] },
        {$and: [ {wednesdayStart: {$gte: 9}}, {wednesdayEnd: {$lte: 12}}]}
        ]
    })
```